# Fetch data from array return in redis command

Tags: javascript, redis

I have a code

```
var redis = require("redis"), client = redis.createClient(6379, '192.168.1.48');
client.on("error", function (err) {
    console.log("Error " + err);
});
    client.sadd("hoang","post:1");
    client.sadd("hoang","post:2");
    client.sadd("hoang","post:3");
    client.sadd("hoang","post:4");
    client.sadd("hoang","post:5");
    client.sadd("hoang","post:7");

    client.sadd("lan","post:1");
    client.sadd("lan","post:2");
    client.sadd("lan","post:3");
    client.sadd("lan","post:4");
    client.sadd("lan","post:5");
    client.sadd("lan","post:6");

    var arr = client.sinter("hoang","lan");
    console.log(arr.length);
```

And console print

> undefined

How to do i feetch array from redis command.

Comment: What is `client`? Is it an instance of something you wrote? A static class? Is it *any* object, and `sadd` is an extension method? (*I assume Javascript has extension methods - I'm a C# developer*).

Comment: client is redis client :D, i updated my ans

Comment: Hmm. I can't see anything obvious you're doing wrongly from [this page](http://redis.io/commands/sinter) on redis.io. Perhaps somebody more familiar will be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `client.sinter` returns a value, you need a callback function, something like:

```
client.sinter(["hoang","lan"], function(err, res){
  console.log(res, res.length);
})
```

Please provide a link to the redis client you are using if you need more info.